# Convertir un XML a un array en PHP

Tags: php, array, xml, api

estoy conectado a una API que me retorna una estructura de datos por medio de formato XML, la idea es convertir esos datos en un array asociativo que pueda manejar y poder hacer lo que necesito, pero no encuentro una solución clara, si alguien me puede ayudar, quedaría sumamente agradecido

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código que tienes? También sería útil que compartes al menos una fracción del `XML` que recibes

Answer (score 0):

Por favor, checa la documentación de cómo realizar preguntas a través del siguiente enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

De igual forma, te comparto un ejemplo de como llevar de XML a array en PHP.

Para ello hacemos uso de la extensión SimpleXML para PHP, generalmente viene por defecto en las instalaciones de PHP, sino puedes instalarla a través de:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.installation.php

**Acá el ejemplo**

```html
<!-- Tu código XML -->
<data Version="1.0">
   <persona>
     <datosPersonales>
       <nombre name="John" />
       <apellido lastName="Doe"/>
     </datosPersonales>
   </persona>
</data>
```

```js
//Tú código PHP
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

//Se imprime los valores por pantalla
echo $xml->persona->datosPersonales->nombre['name'];
echo $xml->persona->datosPersonales->lastName['lastName'];

// O usas un foreach para recorrer los valores

foreach ($xml->persona->datosPersonales as $element) {
  foreach($element as $key => $val) {
    echo "{$key}: {$val}";
  }
}
```